# JSON Jquery Case Insensitive Matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON and Jquery Code:

**JSON**

```
{
    "employees":[
        {
            "name": "Sandy"
        },
        {
            "name": "Megan"
        },  
        {
            "name": "Pat"
        },
        {
            "name": "Susan"
        }
    ]
}
```

**JQuery**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "myJson.json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: function(response){
                        $("input#myInput").live("keyup", function(e){

                            var val = $("input#myInput").val();
                            var len = $("input#myInput").val().length;

                            for (var x = 0; x < response.employees.length; x++) {

                                var empName = response.employees[x].name;
                                var valChar = val.substring(0, len);
                                var nameChar = empName.substring(0, len);

                                if (nameChar.search(valChar) != -1) {
                                    $("ul#myList").append("<li>" + empName + "</li>");
                                }                               
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" width="25" id="myInput">
        <ul id="myList"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What I want to do**

When I type a character in the input field such as M/P/S, it should loop through the JSON file and return matching results. So,

- M will return Megan
- S will return Sandy and Susan
- P will return Pat

**Problem**

Currently, my code is working. BUT only when I input the characters in upper case. If I type in m/p/s, it does not return anything.

**How can I make this case-insensitive so that it works for both**

- M/P/S
- m/p/s

Comment: before searching (comparing) force both strings to be the same case, ie all lowercase.

Comment: Add "if(len === 0) return;" before you begin to loop or else a keystroke on a non alpha key will cause all names to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Some improvements in your code

1. val and `val.substring(0,len)` is same so you don't need to do do substring as len is calculated from val.
2. You don't need to do search as you use substring and get the exact length of val.. so you can do a simple `==` comparision

   ```
      for (var x = 0; x < resp.employees.length; x++) {

           var empName = resp.employees[x].name;
           var valChar = val.toLowerCase();
           var nameChar = empName.substring(0, len).toLowerCase();

           if (nameChar === valChar) {
               $("ul#myList").append("<li>" + empName + "</li>");
           }                               
       }
   ```

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/GpgzS/1/)

Change your for loop as below,

```
        for (var x = 0; x < resp.employees.length; x++) {

            var empName = resp.employees[x].name;
            var valChar = val.substring(0, len).toLowerCase();
            var nameChar = empName.substring(0, len).toLowerCase();

            if (nameChar.search(valChar) != -1) {
                $("ul#myList").append("<li>" + empName + "</li>");
            }                               
        }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/GpgzS/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at .toUpperCase()
IE, 
    if(val.toUpperCase() == search.toUpperCase())