# Search through JSON file and show results with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my search.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="search.js"></script>
 <LINK href="map.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<input id="searchterm" type="text" /> <button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="application/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

This is my search.js:

```
      $("#searchterm").keyup(function(e){
    var q = $("#searchterm").val();
    $.getJSON("http://hello.com/mydata.json",
    {
      srsearch: q,
      action: "query",
      list: "search",
      format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
      $("#results").empty();
      $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
      $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item){
        $("#results").append(item.name);
      });
    });
  });
```

I want the results show up on the page. It should look through the JSON file and then return the name of the item(s) found in the JSON search. Each object in the JSON file has a property of name.

I get this error:

TypeError: data.query is undefined
$.each(data.query.search, function(i, item){

Comment: can you show the json file ?

Comment: http://www.andrewkind.com/cem/data.json

Comment: Are you sure every object in the JSON file has a property of name?

Comment: I had changed it to the correct property name, forgot about that. In this case cemetery_name.

Comment: The property name is case-sensitive, so 'CEMETERY_NAME'.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did try upper case, I still receive the data.query.search is undefined error. I wonder whats going on.

Comment: What is data.query.search? Does your returned JSON have a `'query'` property? It looks to me like you should be passing simply `data` to `$.each`.

Comment: I see. I tried switching it and get TypeError: a is undefined

...turn function(b){return db(a,b).length>0}}),contains:fb(function(a){return funct...

Comment: You should try `console.log(data);` to see what you are getting returned from the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Jquery Case Insensitive Matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435161/json-jquery-case-insensitive-matching)